# Swift: Return class constrained with generic type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a basic generic class:

```
class SharedClass<T> {}
```

And a builder for it:

```
class SharedClassBuilder {
    func build<T>() -> SharedClass<T>? {
        return ...
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do, is return an instance that inherits `SharedClass`, and conforms to `T`. For example:

```
protocol MyObject {
    func doIt()
}

var result: SharedClass<MyObject>? = SharedClassBuilder().build()
result?.doIt()
```

Unfortunately, the Swift compiler complains that the returned type does not have a member named `doIt`.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's not so much that you want the returned class to be constrained by the generic type, as you're asking the returned class to be an *instance of* the constrained type. In your snippet, you're expecting the unwrapped `result` to conform to `MyObject`. Taking this a step further, it means that the conformance of `SharedClass` is determined entirely from how it was constructed. As far as I know this isn't supported in Swift.

However, there's nothing stopping you having a member of `SharedClass` that is a `T`. Something along the lines of:

```
class SharedClass<T>  {
    var v : T?
}

class SharedClassBuilder {
    func build<T>() -> SharedClass<T>? {
        return SharedClass()
    }
}

protocol MyObject {
    func doIt()
}

var result: SharedClass<MyObject>? = SharedClassBuilder().build()
result?.v?.doIt()
```

Comment: That might be a decent option, thanks! Essentially what I'm after is the ability to return some kind of dynamic proxy object that conforms to `T`, probably based off of `NSProxy`. Swift doesn't like the idea of returning `T` directly, probably because it can't be instantiated.

Comment: Indeed. Swift likes to know the type of everything at compile time, to provide more guarantees about code safety. However, if you're willing to restrict yourself to classes that inherit from `NSObject`, then you can implement this fine (essentially as `NSProxy` does). You'll lose a some of the static guarantees, but you might not care.

You could also consider losing the `SharedClass`, and having the builder just return a `T`. Especially if you just use protocol type `T`s, everything will work out fine statically.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought of that, the issue with using classes instead of protocols for `T` is you'll have to implement stubbed methods the whole way down, so it becomes a bit strange to implement, whereas if they could pass in a protocol it'd make a bit more sense. If Swift had support for abstract classes this wouldn't be as much of an issue.